# Using Immutable.js Record as Component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

I'm trying to use Record from Immutable.js as State in Class Component. Here is the code:

```
interface INetworkDisplayAreaState {
    layers: List<Layer>;
    translate: { x: number, y: number };
    scale: number;
}

const NetworkDisplayAreaStateRecord = Record<INetworkDisplayAreaState>({
    layers: List(),
    translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    scale: 1
});

class NetworkDisplayAreaState extends NetworkDisplayAreaStateRecord {
    constructor(state: Partial<INetworkDisplayAreaState> = {}) {
        super(state);
    }
}

export default class NetworkDisplayArea
    extends React.Component<INetworkDisplayAreaProps, NetworkDisplayAreaState> {

    constructor(props: INetworkDisplayAreaProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = new NetworkDisplayAreaStateRecord({ layers: props.layers });
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: INetworkDisplayAreaProps, prevState: NetworkDisplayAreaState) {
        return prevState.set('layers', nextProps.layers);
    }

    // Other component methods go here.
}
```

When component is just created it works fine, but when `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called for the second time, `prevState` has type Object, not my class, and has no prototype, therefore `set` is undefined. I've tried to debug this issue and found that in React internals it merges states for memoization using `Object.assign`, and at that moment all prototypes are removed.

Is there any way how I can still use Record as component's state? Or do I have to use plain JS object instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of luck for using a Record as the top-level state object, as you saw.  But you can probably have the React state contain a single field that is a Record and contains all of your actual data.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected this way. Looks little clumsy, but still better than plain JS object in my case.